# How to get a row with no value in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with every campaign, that table has it's name and the number of emitted coupons. The table client_campaign connects the campaign with the client (campaign_id and client_id), so if a client subscribes a campaign, he gets a coupon.
I want to get a query with the number of emitted and used coupons. I started of with this:

```
select name, emitted_coupons, count(campaign_id) as used_coupons
from campaign, client_campaign
where campaign.campaign_id = client_campaign.campaign_id
group by name, emitted_coupons;
```

The problem is that my implementation doesn't show the campaigns where no coupon was used. I would like to know if it's possible to do all this using only one query and not changing the tables.

Comment: You are looking for an outer join. But that can not be expressed with the ancient and outdated implicit join you are using. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html

Comment: can you share some sample data of `campaign` and `client_campaign` tables? @Loboh67

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the NULL keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value IS NULL;
```